# turning div boxes into hotlinks, without overwriting the buttons they already have - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to turn the whitespace inside the pink boxes you see below into links associated with each object. I have been trying to just make the box clickable to google.com, and numerous tries do not swap the appropriate element. My most recent attempt is looks as follows, where the first jquery function of hovering over "article" does work, but the new one below it doesn't. The page is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/codyc54321/zpLy3og8/1/

```
$( ".linkbox" ).hover(
  function() { 
    $( this ).attr("href", "www.google.com")
}, function() {
  $( this ).attr("href", "#")
}
);
```

I need the Archive/Edit/Delete buttons to retain their functionality, even though the sit within the larger pink box. How can I make this box clickable without overriding my other 3 buttons using jquery?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the html source of the relative section of the page from the browser instead of including all the backend stuff, since that is irrelevant?

Comment: Update [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpLy3og8/) to look like your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to stop propagation on click of your anchor to avoid to events firing. Like below:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

To activate click on your outer div, you may add the below function:

```
$('.article-link').on('click',function(){
  // Do something
});
```

Wrap both these function inside document.ready and you are good to go.

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit on what was causing the propagation issue and what propagation is generally in your own words before I accept

Comment: The anchors on your site are wrapped inside div elements, which means that the anchors are child elements of your div. When you add a click event to child only, it stays with only child. But when you add a click event to the parent, this flows down to the child as part of inheritance from the ancestor. So while you click on child, it fires the click of child, and then, it fires the click of the parent ( child being part of parent, the click is also identified as click of parent). That's where the problem occurs.